# PHP & HTML Alternate syntax for foreach: Undefined variable

Tags: php, html, foreach, notice

**EDIT:** I am using wamp in these examples.

There must be something I have not figured out about the PHP & HTML alternate syntax in foreach.

The following code results in

> Notice: Undefined variable: array1Value in index.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: array2Value in index.php on line 12

```
1: <?php
2: $array1 = getArray1(); // Returns an array with values
3: $array2 = getArray2(); // Also returns an array with values
4: ?>
5:
6:    <div class="doNotRemoveDiv">
7:        <? foreach($array1 as $array1Value): ?>
8:            <?= $array1Value ?>
9:        <? endforeach; ?>
10:
11:       <? foreach($array2 as $array2Value): ?>
12:           <?= $array2Value ?>
13:       <? endforeach; ?>
14:   </div>
```

I've also tried

```
$array1 = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
$array2 = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
```

There must be something really obvious here, and I am just dumb.

P.S. I am aware I could do it like this:

```
6:    <div class="doNotRemoveDiv">
7:        <?php foreach($array1 as $array1Value) {
8:            echo $array1Value;
9:        } ?>
10:   </div>
```

And that works, but I really want to understand why my example doesn't work.

Comment: on line 8 and 12 you are just calling the variable like $array1Value, you don't wanna echo the variable ?

Comment: Ah, that example wasn't actually in use. I was just pointing out that I've managed to get that working. Fixing it anyways. xD

Comment: @PavanJiwnani do you know that the `<?= $var ?>` notation is equivalent to `<?php echo $var ?> ?`

Comment: @SirDarius i wasn't aware of that, it wasn't working on wamp so I thought he forgot to echo the variable

Comment: @PavanJiwnani Oh yeah, that reminds me, I should probably mention it's on wamp.

Comment: It's possible that PHP isn't picking up `<?` to indicate the start of PHP syntax, meaning the foreach doesn't exist in PHP's scope. Try `<?php foreach`

Comment: @BenFortune That gives me a following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file`

Comment: @Annoctatio You're doing the same for `endforeach;` too right?

Comment: @BenFortune ... No. I wasn't. Perhaps I should take a break, catch some air and something. The problem was because I hadn't enabled `short_open_tag` in wamp configurations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting only one warning each, right?

That’s because your loops did not actually execute – since you used `<?` only on your foreach statements, and if `short_open_tags` is off, that means your loop statements don’t execute at all – and so the variables are not set in the first place. But then you try to output them using `<?=`, and that works regardless of the aforementioned setting.

(And after you fix that, you will still get warnings for your second loop, because in the `foreach` statement you used `$array2Value` with an uppercase `V`, but then `$array2value` with a lowercase `v` inside the loop.)

Comment: This fixed it. Right, it seems that I should quit coding for today. If I had 15 Rep, I'd upvote this answer.

(Regarding the second warning, I didn't post the real code here since it wouldn't have clear enough for it to be of use to other people.)

Comment: Well to your credit, this error is a little hard to spot, since you are getting a warning referring to the line of code _inside_ the loop, so you’d be tempted to think _“well my loop must have iterated at least once then, otherwise that line of code would not have executed in the first place, right?”_. That the warning showed up only once, although one would expect it to show up as many times as the loop should run was the clue here that something wasn’t working with the loop itself.

Comment: Heh, I guess that train of thought is what differentiates a beginner and someone who's been doing this stuff for a while. My thought was _"It's informing me of undefined variable, that means there must be something wrong with function or the way I am assigning value to the variable, but I've tried manually assigning the value and it doesn't work. There must be something wrong with the syntax."_

Answer (score 3):

You have to enable the `short_open_tag` configuration value to use the short tags `<?` instead of `<?php`. Since PHP 5.4.0, you can use `<?=` without enabling this directive